# What is the meaning of 刚 in 变形金刚?

Tags: meaning, character-components

I came across the word 变形金刚 in a short children's story that I read and Pleco dictionary states that it refers to either shape-shifting warriors protecting the Buddha, or Transformers (which Google displays almost exclusively if you search the term).  Obviously the connection between the 2 meanings is clear.

But I'm unsure what is the meaning of 刚 in this phrase.  I asked my wife but she even believed the character is 钢 so didn't have a suitable answer.

Is there a historic meaning of 刚, or a historical transformation (!) from another character to this current one, which would enlighten me as to why this character is used in this phrase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「剛」originally meant *unyielding/stubborn/strong*. **金剛** is a traditional phrase which is also used to translate a Buddhist word from Sanskrit (**वज्र**, ***vajra***).

***Vajra*** (PIE root: **weǵ-*, English descendants: *watch, wake, **vigor**, vigil*) is seen by Buddhists as variously a *thunderbolt* or *diamond*, symbolising *extreme hardness/power/indestructibility*, and by semantic extension a kind of symbol or weapon, and further extension a guardian (spirit) which holds this weapon.

As you’ve already seen, 變形金剛 is a reference to Buddhist temple guardian statues (see 四大金剛) which each hold a kind of *vajra* (the weapon).

Comment: I think a full answer must explain why 金刚 was used to refer to a warrior defending the Buddha.

Comment: @JamesHill I hope I clarified what I wrote before. Let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The name 变形金刚 is created / translated when the origin transformer cartoon series (トランスフォーマー) was bought from Japan.  As with other answers, 金刚 is a common references from the four protector deities - 四大金剛 - that guards the gate of heaven (China) or Buddhist temple (India).

As to your question, 剛 have a implication of indestructible / unyielding. 金, as a commonly known hardest metal at the time being, is added to the phase to enhance its meaning.  Thus it is widely used such as:

金剛狼 - wolverine
金剛戰士 - Power Rangers

Answer (score 1):

According to [baidu baike](https://wapbaike.baidu.com/item/%E9%87%91%E5%88%9A%E4%B8%8D%E5%9D%8F%E4%B9%8B%E8%BA%AB/20397859), 金刚 refers to 金刚石 diamond, which is very hard/firm/tough to break.

So, figuratively, 金刚 can refer to someone whose body is as hard/strong/firm as 金刚石, implying he is very strong and powerful. For example, 四大金刚，金刚不坏之身， etc.

变形金刚 is '金刚' whose body can shift and form different objects.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with "钢". Agree with @droooze, just one comment that @droooze is using traditional Chinese. 變形金剛 is just 变形金刚 in simplified Chinese. BTW, there is another translation of 金刚, in English -- King Kong. :)